# Configuring location of AppWidgetset.gwt.xml in Mojo's gwt-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, gwt, vaadin, vaadin7

Im trying to upgrade a vaadin 7 app to use gwt 2.8.2. In order to do so, after changing the dependencies and setting up the gwt-maven-plugin to compile (instead of the vaadin-maven-plugin), I'm running into an issue as by default, the gwt-maven-plugin expects to find the AppWidgetset.gwt.xml in the src/main/java folder. Is there a config to point the plugin at a different location such as a resources folder?

I have tried configuring the vaadin-maven-plugin to create/update the AppWidgetset file at src/main/java, and though it compiles, it gives the following error when calling mvn jetty:run

```
INFO: Requested resource [/VAADIN/widgetsets/org.vaadin.alump.lazylayouts.demo.DemoWidgetSet/org.vaadin.alump.lazylayouts.demo.DemoWidgetSet.nocache.js] not found from filesystem or through class loader. Add widgetset and/or theme JAR to your classpath or add files to WebContent/VAADIN folder.
```

Answer (score 0):

> setting up the gwt-maven-plugin to compile (instead of the vaadin-maven-plugin)

You are not supposed to remove vaadin-maven-plugin. From Vaadin 7.7 onwards there is a possibility to change the GWT version used, there is a blog post [How to use GWT 2.8 in Vaadin applications today](https://vaadin.com/blog/how-to-use-gwt-2-8-in-vaadin-applications-today) on Vaadin website with step by step instructions how to do that.

Comment: Thank you. I was actually following the same article. However the issue turned out to be that there was an annotation in the code pointing to an expected location for the AppWidgetset.gwt.xml. Removing that solved the issues I had when trying to run the app.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I had the following annotation in the main UI class which pointed at the old location of the AppWidgetset.gwt.xml :

```
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = DemoUI.class, widgetset = "org.vaadin.alump.lazylayouts.demo.DemoWidgetSet")
```

Changing this to the below solved the issue I was having:

```
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = DemoUI.class)
```